# How to select button with text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel

Is it possible to select buttons using the text property in jQuery?

I was trying like:

```
$.each(data, function(index, element){
    if(element.table_aval == 0)
    {
         var elmt = element.table_no;
         $('#table button[text='+elmt+']').css('color','red');
    }
});
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Try `:contains` selector.

Comment: $('#table button:contains('+elmt+')').css('color', 'red');  like this???

Comment: Yes. Also, it is better to use CSS class than inline CSS.

Comment: but it is not working..

Comment: data is array get by ajax i.e table rows

Answer (score 22):

The [`:contains` selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) allows you to select elements containing a specific string.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button:contains("Text")').css({'color': 'red'})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Text</button>

<button>Something Different</button>
```

Comment: Please provide more details on what `data` is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data, function(index, element){
    if(element.table_aval == 0){
       var elmt = element.table_no;
       $("button:contains(text='+elmt+')").css('color','red');
}});
```